# Rails Twitter-Boostrap : Load many assets files (javascript and css)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just started to use twitter-boostrap gem for my simple app.
When I check it loads some many javascript file which I believed it does not use in a particular page. just like show in the following image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XaSI.png

So the question, is it possible to manage which js file should be loaded in a page?

Thanks.

Comment: This is going to add complexity when you deploy -- you're going to have to add each file you need to be precompiled by the asset pipeline. Is this something you want to do? (I recommend not).

Comment: Yes, at time moment this is would be fine, since this would be small app.

Comment: I just don't think this is the right move, so I'm going to not answer. But you're able to only include the bootstrap files you want, and then tell config/environments/production to compile each.